# Is this pronuncation of "serious" or "series" correct?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Merriam-Webster says that the pronunciation of "serious" or "series" is

**ˈsir-ē-əs**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serious

But I do not make the **si** sound ("sin"), I made the **sē** sound ("see") in the first syllable. My pronunciation is **ˈsēr-ē-əs** (see-ri-ous).

In the word "*seer*" Merriam Webster allows 2 pronounciations, one of which is **sē**,

**ˈsir & ˈsē-ər**

but it doesn't do that for "serious" or "series." So is my pronunciation incorrect? I'm in the USA.

Comment: Where do you get that pronunciation of series? I only see ˈsir-(ˌ)ēz  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/series Without going into the precise phonology, it's probably to do with how the sound before /r/ is pronounced and transcribed, versus in other contexts. And if you listen to their recording of "series" it's quite clearly not the sound they transcribe ē (IPA /i:/). But accents vary so you may pronounce it differently.

Comment: Have you listened to the recorded (audio) pronunciation MW provides? This may just be a matter of notation.

Comment: ***Cirrus*** (cloud) is the same initial vowel as ***serious*** for me - which is *not* the same as ***see*** (I'm surprised if there's a dialect where they're homophones, but I won't argue). But it *might* be the same as ***searing*** (heat) - in some contexts vowels are articulated a bit longer or shorter, I dunno.

Comment: Serious: U.S. /ˈsɪriəs/ -- Series U.S. /ˈsɪriz/ (The accent may alter the pronunciation.)

Comment: Anyone remember John McEnroe's catch phrase ["You cannot be serious!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0hK1wyrrAU&t=3s). The first syllable definitely sounds like the first syllable of "searing".

Comment: US dictionaries cannot be trusted with pronunciation. If you must refer to US pronunciation, use [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater), which is phonemic and doesn't use silly spelling pronunciations. In most American dialects, there is no difference between tense /i/ and lax /ɪ/ before /r/. It doesn't matter which one you say because they don't contrast. The same is true for tense /u/ and lax /ʊ/ before /r/.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's what I thought. I thought that the i/ɪ before "r" is always a moot point. Some specialists I've asked have said that they've heard both i/ɪ in "mirror" for example. Just surprised why "US dictionaries can't be trusted with pronunciation" -- that's kind of their purpose.

Comment: US dictionaries still use some variant (each is different) of Noah Webster's spelling-based system, invented before Western science discovered phonetics, hence useless for indicating spelling to non-native or illiterate speakers. They apparently think Americans are too stupid to learn English phonemes, and I'm sorry to say they're probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

In most North American acccents, there is no possible contrast between the vowel sound of *sin* and that of *see* when followed directly by an /r/ without a break. See this English Language Learners Stack Exchange question for information about the variation in which actual sound is used in this context: [-eer vowel (accent/dialect variation?)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72065)

The two pronunciations Merriam Webster gives for "seer" differ by syllabification: one (ˈsir) is a monosyllable, a homophone of "sear", and the other (ˈsē-ər) is a disyllable.